# Which connections are needed for Media Manager Connector?

Tags: 2011, media-manager

We want to install the Media Manager Connector inside our firewall. The Media Manager instance that we want to connect to is out on the Internet.

I guess this will have some impact on my firewall configuration. Which ports should be opened between the CMS server and Media Manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Media Manager Connector communicates to Media Manager through a web service. It only uses HTTP port 80.

All connections are to the VMS host, i.e. [vms name].sdlmedia.com.